# Custom theorem title style

Tags: theorems, amsthm

I have been trying everything to get my theorems to look like this:

[image]

The best I could do was defining

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{hypo}{Hypomnema}
```

in the preamble and then adding the good old

```
\textit{what the theorem's about}
```

right after the `\begin{hypo}`. (Brute force, and hard to keep track of once the theorems start growing in number)

Is there a way to modify the theorem style so that something like

```
\begin{hypo}[what the theorem's about]
```

will give me the same outcome?

Comment: `\theoremstyle{plain}` (which is the default) should give you what you want.

Comment: Well, that is not really what I want. The title in `plain` goes in parentheses and before the period, while i need it to be as in the picture above

Comment: Your question was not clear to me. You wan the result to be ‘**Hypomnema**. *What the theorem's about*. Blah blah’, with the body in upshape. italic? same line, next line?

Answer (score 1):

With amsthm and thmtools:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  notebraces={}{},
  notefont=\normalfont\itshape,
  headpunct={\normalfont.},
  headformat={\NAME\ \NUMBER.\NOTE},
  spaceabove=\topsep,
  spacebelow=\topsep,
  ]{noparens}
\declaretheorem[
  style=noparens,
  name=Hypomnema,
  ]{hypo}

\begin{document}

\begin{hypo}[On Seidel's product representation of the natural logarithm]
Some text
\end{hypo}

\begin{hypo}[what the theorem's about]
More text
\end{hypo}

\end{document}
```

[image: theorems]